# jquery php ajax username check function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So i'm usually pretty good at figuring out these types of problems but this one has got me completely stumped as have been trying to fix for about 6 hours now.

i have a web form which contains a username check using jquery script and a php script. it was working fine when i first wrote the code and now has completely stopped working(no idea why). The php script is a pretty standard mysqli query which returns the numrows and then i either echo 1 or 0 to the page depending on if a result was found. this script works fine and have tested it independently and echos 1 if no result was found and 0 if a result was found.

in the jquery script i have a min value check and a no value check which both work fine. Then my ajax call and i receive the result with success:function(data). this also has been tested independently by printing the result(data) on screen and prints a 1 on screen when there is no record and a 0 on screen when a record if found so i know everything is working fine with the sent data and im getting the results back i expect.

so my only thing left is there must be a problem with my if statement and how it is dealing with the returned data as it always skips to the else even when the condition is met. The only way for the if statement to work is when i set the variable myself and run the script. The long story short is everything works fine except for the final if statement where it always jumps to the else no matter what and says the username is available even when i know its not.

Im testing on xampp. Could this be an issue too?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!!

Here is the code: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){  


  //the min chars for username  
        var usermin_chars = 6; 

        //result texts  
        var checking_html = 'Checking...';  

//when button is clicked  
    $('#username').blur(function(){  
         var usernameVal = $("#username").val();
        if (usernameVal == '') {
        $("#username_result").html('<span class="error">Please enter a username!</span>');
        $('#username').removeClass();
        $('#username').addClass("form_error");
     }
        //run the character number check  
       else if($('#username').val().length < usermin_chars){  
            //if it's bellow the minimum show characters_error text '  
            $('#username_result').html('<span class="error">Username must contain at least 6 characters!</span>'); 
            $('#username').removeClass();
            $('#username').addClass("form_error"); 
        }else{  
            //get the username  
    var username = $('#username').val();  

    $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"checkUsername.php",
                data:"username="+username,
                    success:function(data){
                    if(data==0){$("#usename_result").html("Username already in use! Please choose another username.");
                    $('#username').removeClass();
                    $('#username').addClass("form_error"); 
                    }
                    else{$("#username_result").html("Username available");
                    $('#username_result').html('<span class="ok"><img src="../images/imgs/available.png" width="20" height="20" margin-left="5" alt="tick"></span>');
                    $('#username').removeClass();
                    $('#username').addClass("form_ok");
                    }
                }
             });

        }  
    });  

});
```

Comment: fiddle or nothing ;p

Comment: What have you tried to debug ? There's no magic in that, if it goes into the èlse`clause, it means `data!=0`. Now inspect your return through a network inpector to see if it is the server sending it wrong or your client code failing. I guess it's your server, and most probably your query...

Comment: Your Code  in `checkUsername.php` is wrong

Comment: The php page has been tested independently and with the javascript it always returns the correct result and stores it in the variable (data)

Comment: @MartynClinton , dont write an essay , dont have time to read ,I didnt understand your issue,make is small nd short

Comment: it has also been tested in firbug and i always get the correct http response 1 or 0 depending on what i input

Comment: Can you comment your code properly or create a fiddle?

Comment: After `if(data==0)`,  the name `username_result` is spelled wrong. Try fixing that and in the `else` block, do alert(data) in the code as it is to know for sure how the value is being handled by the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found the answer. as the site is near completion i had gone through all the pages and made sure every page had a title for SEO including the checkUser page. the page title was being sent through with the data and confusing the if statement. when i was testing the fuction if i placed (data) in a span it only showed the 0 or 1 but looking at it in firebug it showed the response as the 0 or 1 plus the page title. Thanks for those who had a look at it.